# What connector type is on this old IBM laptop internal HD?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, thinkpad

So, I am trying to wipe this drive to sell the ThinkPad 390X laptop. Yes, it was in a caddy with a number stamped on (34.43B27.XXXR01) - I've gently removed it and the connector is part of the drive - which is an IBM Travelstar (see pics).

I cannot connect this to a Sabrent SATA-to-USB device I just bought (which works for other PC drives). The connection type is different. I can't find it anywhere online either.

Connector:

[image: connector]

Drive:

[image: drive]

Comment: You can't use a SATA to USB converter with an IDE HDD.

Comment: Are you sure it's not [detachable](https://www.amazon.com/NEC-Laptop-44-Pin-Connector-HDD-IDECON/dp/B0843P2XH9)?

Comment: Yes that is a detachable connector on the hard drive, remove it to expose the standard IDE connection.

Comment: Aside from connecting your drive, and using a computer to erase, if the drive has spinning platters(magnetic encoding) you can also use a degaussing coil to demagnetize a hard drive. I like to disassemble, degauss, and physically crush very old, unusable drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an IBM design for that laptop and is an IDE connection. That is a very old machine.

An external caddy with both connectors (IDE and Sata) will work. I have a Sabrent in the basement
with both types, so you can get a working adapter

You can put the drive in a proper caddy and get the data from it.

Comment: Yes, I got it in college many years ago. I can't load any deletion software on to the machine because it has no USB drive! I'm told it is worth a lot more with the drive - maybe I can just sell it and not worry about personal data - none of it would really be relevant now.